# Unable to create merged directory when executing test in chrome

Tags: docker, dart, angular-dart

I have started to receive "Unable to create merged directory" error during executing tests in docker container. Command to execute test:

```
pub run build_runner test --fail-on-severe --delete-conflicting-outputs -- -p chrome
```

Output:

```
[SEVERE] Unable to create merged directory for /tmp/build_runner_testFCULZJ/.
[SEVERE] Failed after 1m 14s
```

There were two changes:

1. docker image with chrome was created from 2.7 instead 2.5
2. `build_web_compilers` dev dependecy version was increased: `^1.0.0` -> `^2.9.0`

Not sure what is the reason - docker image not allows to create or build_runner issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was test sources was not included(test source folder was excluded in `build.yaml`):

```
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      - lib/**
      - web/**
      - pubspec.*
```